# Flutter how to avoid PageView items being called multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart

I noticed that my items inside my `PageView.Builder` are **called multiple times**, if I start swiping to the next page. As I learned so far, listening to the values of the `pagecontroller` with `addListeners()` does its job. It seems like this is also the reason, why my items inside the `PageView.Builder` are called multiple times.

How can I prevent that? Every time I swipe, I want it only called a single time.

**This is my pageview (simplified code, `ChildItem` is wrapped by `GestureDetector`):**

```
  var currentPageValue = 0.0;
  PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 1, keepPage: false);



@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      controller..addListener(() {
      setState(() {     
        currentPageValue = controller.page;
      });
    });
  }

 body: PageView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: controller,
           itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: list[i],
              child: Transform(
                child: ChildItem(), <--- This is beeing called multiple times when swiping
                transform: animationController(context, i),
                alignment: animationAlignmentController(context, i),
              ),
            ),
            childCount: list.length,
          ),
        ));
```